# django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError with form post data

Tags: python, django

`django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: "'user_data'"`

Is what i get when trying to access user_data from the request.POST

```
post_data = dict(request.POST)
print(post_items)
```

returns

```
{'user_data[first_name]': ['Jamie'], 'user_data[name_last]': ['Lannister'], 'campus': ['McHale Hall'], 'user_data[twitter]': ['@jamielan']}
```

So if I try to get just the user_data, I try this (doesn't work)

```
post_data = dict(request.POST)
user_data = post_data['user_data']
```

I just want to get all instances of user_data in this dict and store as json. How can I do that?

Expected out put would be something like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `POST` data is really weird but for the sake of correctness, you should do:

```
first_name = post_data["user_data[first_name]"]
name_last = post_data["user_data[name_last]"]
```

Because the string `user_data[first_name]` is the key for the dict not just string `user_data`.

**Edit:**

If you want to convert user data into dict, you should loop on `request.POST` and check for keys that contains `user_data` keyword:

```
user_data = {}
for key, value in request.POST.iteritems():
    if 'user_data' in key:
        field = key.split('[')[1].replace(']', '')
        user_data[key] = value

# convert into json
json_user_data = json.dumps(user_data)
```

Comment: Hmm user_data is extremely long, i'm not sure if its correct literally making a variable for each item that may or may not be there.

Comment: I don't know what do you want to do with `request.POST`, but I edited my answer.

Comment: No offence on this but sounds like you were generally unclear about python itself and django(by the questions you asked recently). I suggest you follow some official django tutorials before jumping into programming, it will save a lot of time struggling on questions like this.

Comment: No offense taken :) I read the docs, and I don't really learn from reading. I learn best by doing. Figured stackoverflow could help me through some of these parts.